# Build shared object from Fortran source with package(e.g. LAPACK) for R

Tags: r, dll, fortran, lapack

I am new to create shared objects for R from Fortran sources. Perhaps some of my questions do not make sense. However, I have searched a lot about my questions but still get no clear answer. So, I would like to figure out what the big picture to create these shared objects(.dll files)in R is.

According some tutorials and manuals, I need to prepare a Fortran file *mymodf.f*, which contains only subroutines, similarly as below:

```
c file mymodf.f
   subroutine initmod(odeparms)
    external odeparms
    double precision parms(3)
    common /myparms/parms

     call odeparms(3, parms)
    return
   end

   subroutine derivs (neq, t, y, ydot, yout, ip)
    ....
    return
   end

   subroutine jac (neq, t, y, ml, mu, pd, nrowpd, yout, ip)
    ....
    return
   end
c end of file mymodf.f
```

In order to create the shared object, it requires the following code:

```
system("R CMD SHLIB mymodf.f")
```

I want to use the subroutines in LAPACK to solve some linear equations or inverse matrices. What should I do so that I can call the subroutines in LAPACK? I ask this question because one needs to install packages in R to call some extra functions or one needs to add `#include <xxxx.h>` as header in C to call some extra functions in xxxx.h. Just the same situation.

Also, I have downloaded lapack-3.5.0.tgz from http://www.netlib.org/lapack. Where should I put package to? Do I need to install this .tgz file?

This is not a normal case to code, compile and run a Fortran program. I have some Fortran codes which is not a complete program and I want to complie it as .dll file for R.

Thanks very much for helping!

(FYI, I am working on a Windows 7 PC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a guy who has no experience about generating shared object from Fortran source for R, it is time-consuming to search the answer of the questions I asked above because there are really few tutorials which mention about these. It seems those who have experience about this do not see this thread.

If you want to call subroutines in LAPACK or BLAS, you need to create a file called *Makevars* with no file type which contains:

```
PKG_LIBS=$(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

Remark: you do not need to install libraries LAPACK and BLAS manually, R has already included them. All you need to do is to tell the compiler how to link them by creating the *Makevars* file under same directory of your Fortran source file. For other Fortran libraries, I don't know how to link them. Hope someone can provide a guide.

Then, you need to have a Fortran source, say name it *my.f90* and it contains something like below:

```
  subroutine LIN(a,b)
     implicit none
     integer, parameter :: n=2, nrhs=1
     integer, parameter :: lda=n, ldb=n
     double precision :: a(lda,n), b(ldb,nrhs)
     integer :: info

     call DPOSV('U',n,nrhs,a,lda,b,ldb,info)

  end subroutine LIN
```

The next step is to compile the Fortran code as .dll file in Windows/.so file in Mac (this is so-called creating shared object for R). In order to compile the code in Windows, you need to have Rtools and R installed. Also, the path of your R should be added into "Path" of system variables. (Steps: Right click Computer icon->Properties->Advanced system settings->Environment Variables->Find and select "Path" in System variables->click "Edit" and add the path of your R, for example, `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin;`). Now, you are ready to compile the code. You need to open your R as run as administrator, change to the directory containing the Fortran file and then execute a command in R console:

```
system('R CMD SHLIB my.f90')
```

You will see that the shared object *my.dll* is created under the directory.

The final step is to load the shared object into R and run it. Following my example,

```
dyn.load('my.dll') #load the shared object

a<-diag(c(1,2)) #prepare arguments *a* and *b* for the Fortran subroutine
b<-c(3,4)
.Fortran("LIN",a=as.double(a),b=as.double(b)) #call the Fortran subroutine
```

Remark: you need to unload the shared object from R so that you can delete or compile over it when R is still running:

```
dyn.unload('my.dll')
```